# I have one problem, when I put more than one url, data are overwritten

Tags: csv, web-scraping, scrapy, export-to-csv

I made a simple scrapy script for scraping data from https://www.jobs2careers.com with items and exporting data to csv file. But I have one problem, when I put more than one url, data are overwritten.

I tryed with some other python libraryes, like openpyxl. Maybe there is a problem with running multiple spiders

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from ..items import QuotetutorialItem


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    n = 1
    start_urls = ['https://www.jobs2careers.com/results3.php?q=Fashion&l=Miami%2C+FL&s=00']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = QuotetutorialItem()
        s = Selector(response)
        quote = s.xpath("//div[@id='jobs_container']/div")

        for q in quote:
            url = response.url
            industry = q.xpath("//input[@id='search_q']/@value").get()
            state = q.xpath("//*[@id='results_controller']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/a[3]/text()").get()
            company_name = q.xpath(".//div[@class='companyname']/span[@class='company']/text()").get()
            job_title = q.xpath(".//div[@class='title title1 hidden-xs']/text()").get()

            items['url'] = url
            items['industry'] = industry
            items['state'] = state
            items['company_name'] = company_name
            items['job_title'] = job_title

            yield items

        num = int(response.xpath("//h1[@class='result2']//text()").get().split("\n")[0].replace(',', ''))
        if num > 1000:
            num = 1000
        total = int(num) // 10 + 1
        np = response.url
        np = np[np.rfind('=') + 1:]
        next_page = response.url.replace(np, str((self.n * 10)))
        if self.n < total:
            self.n += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page,callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I put more than one url, data are overwritten" ? When you put more than 1 start_url or urls in the Item? And what data is exactly overwritten?

Comment: For example when i put this                                                                   
start_urls = ['https://www.jobs2careers.com/results3.php?q=Healthcare&l=Chicago%2C+IL&s=00',
                  'https://www.jobs2careers.com/results3.php?q=Fashion&l=Miami%2C+FL&s=00']                                                                           And script finish, I got only 1000 result, combined, so one more url in start_urls   @WimHermans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data are not being overwritten here.

You are getting 1000 items total because you're using `self.n` to limit pagination.

There are callbacks populated from each start_url, and they both increment the spider's `self.n` attribute asynchronously. The first url moves `self.n` from 1 to 2, then the second moves it from 2 to 3, then the first from 3 to 4, and so on. Because it's async, this isn't guaranteed to be the case exactly, but something like this is happening every time.

Answer (score 0):

As pwinz said, it's due to the logic used to go to the next page.
The below code builds the url of the next page based on the current page, and it stops if it reaches 1000 jobs or if the total number of jobs has been reached.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from ..items import JobsItem
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse, urlencode, parse_qsl


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobscareers'
    start_urls = ['https://www.jobs2careers.com/results3.php?q=Healthcare&l=Chicago%2C+IL&s=00',
                  'https://www.jobs2careers.com/results3.php?q=Fashion&l=Miami%2C+FL&s=00%27]']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = JobsItem()
        s = Selector(response)
        quote = s.xpath("//div[@id='jobs_container']/div")

        for q in quote:
            url = response.url
            industry = q.xpath("//input[@id='search_q']/@value").get()
            state = q.xpath("//*[@id='results_controller']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/a[3]/text()").get()
            company_name = q.xpath(".//div[@class='companyname']/span[@class='company']/text()").get()
            job_title = q.xpath(".//div[@class='title title1 hidden-xs']/text()").get()

            items['url'] = url
            items['industry'] = industry
            items['state'] = state
            items['company_name'] = company_name
            items['job_title'] = job_title

            yield items

        num = int(
            response.xpath("//h1[@class='result2']//text()").get().split(
                "\n")[0].replace(',', ''))
        parsed_url = urlparse(response.url)
        query = dict(parse_qsl(parsed_url.query))
        try:
            s = int(query['s'])
        except (ValueError, KeyError):
            s = 0
        if s < 1000 and s <= num:
            new_query = query
            new_query['s'] = str(s + 10)
            next_url = urlunparse(
                parsed_url._replace(query=urlencode(new_query))
            )
            yield scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with urllib.parse so I need to check this.                                                    But I made another script with scrapy and openpyxl and it works quite well.                         Thank you very much for your time.